# React Navigation - Creating a tab navigator element is not working?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to create a tabbed layout using React Navigation.  Here's my code:

```
const Navigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
    Wines,
    Stores,
    Vineyards,
    Restaurants
});

// in render()
<View style={styles.navContainer}>
    <Navigator
        screenProps={this.getScreenProps()}
    />
    <Text>Hello, world!</Text> // Put here for demonstrational purposes
</View>
```

This is what results:

[image]

Basically the navigator isn't taking up any space and I don't know why. I also tried this

```
const Navigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
    Wines: {screen: Wines},
    Stores: {screen: Stores},
    Vineyards: {screen: Vineyards},
    Restaurants: {screen: Restaurants}
});
```

and for the `Navigator` JSX passing in `style={{width: 200, height: 200}}`, but it doesn't seem to do anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A working demo in codesandbox or codepen would help. Not really clear what your issue is

Comment: @charlietfl Here: https://snack.expo.io/HJzfLvvkX. The `Navigator` isn't taking up any space, why?

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure to specify `flexDirection` and `height` style attributes in every `View` you use. I added `height` to the parent view inside `render()` and it works just fine.

Link: https://snack.expo.io/Hy-oLAvJ7